# K8s deamon set high avialibality

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, high-availability

we have a **deamonset** and we want to make it HA (not our deamonset), does the following is applicable for HA for deamaon set also?

- affinity (anti affinity)
- toleration's
- pdb

we have on each cluster 3 worker nodes
I did it in the past for deployment but not sure what is also applicable for deamonset, this is **not our app** but we need to make sure it is HA as it's critical app

**update**

Does it make sense to add the following to deamonset, lets say I've 3 worker nodes and I want it to be scheduled only in `foo` workers nodes?

```
spec:
  tolerations:
    - effect: NoSchedule
      key: WorkGroup
      operator: Equal
      value: foo
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: WorkGroup
      operator: Equal
      value: foo
  nodeSelector:
    workpcloud.io/group: foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked two, somewhat unrelated questions.

> does the following is applicable for HA for deamaon set also?
>
> - affinity (anti affinity)
> - toleration's
> - pdb

A [daemonset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) (generally) runs on a policy of "one pod per node" -- you **CAN'T** make it HA (for example, by using autoscaling), and you will (assuming you use defaults) have as many replicas of the daemonset as you have nodes, unless you explicitly specify which nodes you want to want to run the daemonset pods, using things like `nodeSelector` and/or `tolerations`, in which case you will have less pods. The documentation page linked above gives more details and has some examples

> this is not our app but we need to make sure it is HA as it's critical app

Are you asking how to make your critical app HA? I'm going to assume you are.

If the app is as critical as you say, then a few starter recommendations:

1. Make sure you have at least 3 replicas (4 is a good starter number)
2. Add tolerations if you must schedule those pods on a node pool that has taints
3. Use node selectors as needed (e.g. for regions or zones, but only if necessary do to something like disks being present in those zones)
4. Use affinity to group or spread your replicas. Definitely would recommend using a spread so that if one node goes down, the other replicas are still up
5. Use a [pod priority](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/) to indicate to the cluster that your pods are more important than other pods (beware this may cause issues if you set it too high)
6. Setup notifications to something like PagerDuty, OpsGenie, etc, so you (or your ops team) are notified if the app goes down. If the app is critical, then you'll want to know it's down ASAP.
7. Setup [pod disruption budgets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#pod-disruption-budgets), and [horizontal pod autoscalers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to ensure an agreed number of pods are always up.

Comment: Thanks, Yes we did it for deployment, im asking about deamon set what is relevant for it from what you write

Comment: And the answer is the first part of my answer -- simply put . you can't HA a daemonset.

Comment: just make sure, if I've deamonset the `affinity` & `tollerations` & `pdb` configurations is not relevant ?

Comment: Right, you can't adjust how a daemonset is scheduled -- by nature, it's one per node. Affinity, pdbs, etc, don't do anything.

Comment: Thanks, can You please explain it in the answer, why its not relevant ? i'll close it

Comment: Actually,I stand corercted, I just checked the documentation and it seems things have changed to what I remember. Looks like they DO allow you to use things like selectors and taint.s I will update the answer

Comment: Last question, please see my update, does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it would work, assuming all your labels and taints match up

Answer (score 0):

You can not control the replicas in DaemonSet as DaemonSet will have one pod per node.

you need to change the object to either Deployment or Statefulset to manage the replica count and use the nodeSelector to deploy it in all the nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this is not our deamonset we are installing it via helm, this is critical app and we need to make sure its HA